# Strange quote characters around static java String (on android?)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string

I have a String constant defined in a class:

```
public static final String ABC = "abc";
```

And I want to compare, if another String is equal:

```
String test = "abc";
if (test.equals(OtherClass.ABC)) {
    doSomething();
}
```

This test strangely fails and when I inspect the variables with eclipse, I see that ABC is 2 characters longer than test, and that it looks like this:

```
ABC: "abc"
test: abc
```

Where do those quotes come from and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: The Eclipse editor when debugging will put quotes around Strings by default.

Comment: I can't see how it's possible for that `if` condition to return `false`. Can you provide a compilable example that demonstrates this?

Comment: Those quotes are coming from OtherClass.ABC... code you have not included. Use the replace(String, String) method of String to fix the problem.

Comment: @Kon the test would not fail if it was the debugger's quotes being viewed

Comment: @Kon Eclipse destroys the data in your program during debugging? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @leigero It doesn't modify the data, it just presents a representation of a String object which it puts around quotes as it is a special object in Java. The question of why? can be saved for an Eclipse dev (see their forums)

Comment: @Duncan tried to compile one, but then it works. Maybe it is an android thing? OtherClass is just a helper holding lots of these constants. Will try to boil it down to a "working" example on monday when I'm back at work.

Comment: @Kon it is not putting the quotes around test, only around ABC. And the equal test fails. And the strings show different lengths and the hashCodes differ, etc ... very weird.

Comment: @sigma Very strange indeed. If you are remote debugging, ensure that you are debugging the same codebase version as exists locally. Otherwise, posting a screenshot may be helpful.

Comment: when i think about it, there are other strings like that where the comparison worked, need to look into it more. thanks so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right it does surround the value with extra double quotes in the quick preview.

[image]

But when you inspect the value from the `Expresions` view, then the value is correct. Moreover it fixes the previous behavior of the quick preview

[image]

But still the output is the expected. The two values are equal. I believe this is a bug, since this behavior doesn't make sense to me. I might be wrong though. I don't know if this helped, and if it can be considered as an answer, but I wanted to include the screenshots and the comments don't support that.

The code is not from an android project. Just a simple Java project. I'm using eclipse Kepler.

```
class OtherClass {
    public static final String ABC = "abc";
}

public class MainJsoup {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String test = "abc";
        if (test.equals(OtherClass.ABC)) {
            System.out.println("They are equal.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("They are unequal.");
            System.out.println("OtherClass.ABC = " + OtherClass.ABC);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can see the different lengths in your screenshots, in mine even the hash was different. Probably some odd android thing then, I will investigate more, thank you!

Comment: More of an eclipse odd thing. No problem. I'm glad I could help. Have fun.

Comment: Wow, must have been some weird eclipse caching thing, it was gone today. Can't wait to switch to Android Studio and experience their bugs too. :P thx for the help all!